# OCI CLI create_backup_from_onprem script error

Tags: oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am an encountered an issue while creating database backup using create_backup_from_onprem script in OCI CLI. i noticed that object storage namespace is not correct while executing backup script.

```
[oracle@oracledev oci-cli-scripts]$ ./create_backup_from_onprem --config-file /home/oracle/.oci/config --display-name testimport01 --availability-domain $AD --edition STANDARD_EDITION --opc-installer-dir /home/oracle/migrate --tmp-dir /home/oracle/migrate/onprem_upload --compartment-id $C --rman-password *****

oci._vendor.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://swiftobjectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/v1/dbbackupbom/iF0ydees7V0yWxyuAYtF/parameter.log
```

and parameter.log

```
Either the bucket named 'iF0ydees7V0yWxyuAYtF' does not exist in the namespace 'dbbackupbom' or you are not authorized to access it
```

My correct namespace is bmnoo8fd7ute

```
[oracle@oracledev oci-cli-scripts]$ oci os ns get
{
"data": "bmnoo8fd7ute"
}
```

Not sure how to correct object storage namespace in CLI. could you please any help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the tenant ocid in oci config file, for which the default location is ~/.oci/config. You might do it manually or using the oci setup config command. You can overwrite the current values, or you can create a new profile, which you can refer to in oci calls.
For more information please see the [CLI config file doc](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm).

In case the oci config file is already contains the correct value, you need to reinstall the oci_install specifying the right tenant ocid for -tOCID. (in this case OCID of bmnoo8fd7ute)

```
java -jar oci_install.jar -host swiftobjectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com -pvtKeyFile oci_private_key -pubFingerPrint oci_public_fingerprint -uOCID user_ocid -tOCID tenancy_ocid -walletDir /wallet_directory -libDir /library_directory
```

Update:
As the dbbackupbom is an internal resource ID, you can't change that with the reinstallation of oci_install. Rather this should be an authorization issue.
Please check if you have the right policies in place. If not, create a policy like this: 
Name of the policy: ObjectStorageAccess 
Add below statements: 
Allow group ObjectAdmins to manage buckets in tenancy
Allow group ObjectAdmins to manage objects in tenancy

Finally add your user to ObjectAdmins, or use a different group which you are already part of.

Comment: My tenancy OCID is correct and configured at default location /home/oracle/.oci/config

Comment: So it looks like you have to change the storage URL, which you have set when you installed oci_install. Try reinstalling it using this command and specifying the right tenant at the end. (ocid of bmnoo8fd7ute)
java -jar oci_install.jar
-host https://swiftobjectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com
-pvtKeyFile oci_private_key -pubFingerPrint oci_public_fingerprint 
-uOCID user_ocid -tOCID tenancy_ocid
-walletDir /wallet_directory -libDir /library_directory

Comment: It looks like dbbackupbom is an internal resourceID, which you cannot change. I have just seen a similar one in the Cost Analysis csv for Frankfurt region called dbbackupfra. So it should rather be an authorization issue. I'm investigating further.

Comment: Could you please check if you have the right policies in place? 
If not, create a policy like this:
Name of the policy: 'ObjectStorageAccess'
Add below statements
'Allow group ObjectAdmins to manage buckets in tenancy'
'Allow group ObjectAdmins to manage objects in tenancy'

Finally add your user to ObjectAdmins, or use a different group which you are already part of.

Comment: I tried this as well but it's not working. getting same error.

Comment: This time i have build new server, installed new database. this time i have configured with root user which has access all resources in tenancy as policy (ALLOW GROUP dbgroup to manage all-resources IN TENANCY). but again getting same error as earlier.

Comment: There is an optional parameter you can specify when installing oci_install, which is -bucket. Please try to reinstall it with -bucket <your bucket name>, after you created a bucket on Object Storage.

Comment: oci_installation is completed using bucket parameter. in my case, swiftobjectstorage did not work, instead objectstorage works for me under host parameter. then after i have configured encryption and then backup taken using RMAN. my mission is accomplished. but i am still wondering why backup using ./create_backup_from_onprem did not work ?

Comment: Backup Cloud Service is a part of PaaS and backup taken with RMAN goes to object storage bucket. but ./create_backup_from_onprem script is a part of IaaS and backup taken using this script goes to Standalone backup section under VM/BM Database and then we could easily create new database over VM using those backup. that was my plan.

Answer (score 0):

Adding cross reference to GitHub issue in OCI CLI in case the OCI database team can answer -- https://github.com/oracle/oci-cli/issues/201.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got found correct answer and resolution for this issue.

**Cause:** Error occurred due to newly launched region having some internal bug. i used Mumbai region which was recently launched.

**Resolution** :  Choose another stable region. Ashburn region works for me.